# How to parse AND/OR input in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, parsing, grammar, logical-operators

I want to parse an SQL-like input, for example:

```
SEX = 'MALE' AND AGE > 20
```

Based on the 'sql' input I then search through my c# array of Items.

So for example above, I would search my data for all items that have their Item.Sex property set to 'MALE' and their Item.Age property is greater than 20.

This is a trivial example, and you can easily start imagining more complex scenarios. For example:

```
(SEX = 'MALE' AND AGE > 20) OR (SEX = 'FEMALE' AND AGE < 30)
```

I need to be able to support the following operators:

```
=
>
<
<>
() - for precedence
AND
OR
```

I have a feeling I'll end up having to code this myself from scratch, but don't want to re-invent the wheel.  After looking into this for a bit, I did come across references to parsers/grammar etc, but am not quite sure if those fit the bill.

Comment: You can use tools like ANTLR (or the C# equivalent) or a Parser-Combinator library (if there is one for C#) to make life simpler.

Comment: Have a look at using Expression Trees http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Comment: For an ANTLR & C# demo, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396080/antlr-3-3-c-sharp-tutorials

Comment: @astander Is there a way to go from string -> Expression Tree easily? (I assumed, perhaps incorrectly, the input is text.)

Comment: Not that I am aware of, the other suggestions here seems good though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to parse the input yourself, but with a parser generator such as [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/), it is not too much work.