# ANTLR grammar tutorials

Tags: c#, antlr, antlrworks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ANTLR 3.3 C# Tutorials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396080/antlr-3-3-c-sharp-tutorials)

I want to create grammar for C# application, but I don't know anything about ANTLR. Does anybody know any good tutorials about defining rules, and building them into `.cs` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this one](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=0978739256) is the best book about ANTLR parser generator. I read this book, when i was writing my own MSIL compiler.
You can also look at [my compiler](http://code.google.com/p/wlcompiler/) (it may be not working) for the .g grammar as an example.

p.s.

Official ANTLR project web-site share good samples about grammar rules and parser generating.