# Validating a string mathematical expression

Tags: c#, regex, validation, evaluation

Guys I am working on a system that evaluates string mathematical expression.

my class to carry out the calculation

```
public Double Calculate(string argExpression)
{
    //get the user passed string
    string ExpressionToEvaluate = argExpression;

    //pass string in the evaluation object declaration.
    Expression z = new Expression(ExpressionToEvaluate);

    //command to evaluate the value of the **************string expression
    var result = z.Evaluate();
    Double results = Convert.ToDouble(result.ToString());

    return results;
}
```

And my calling codes.

```
Double Finalstat = calculator.Calculate(UserQuery);
```

Till now my expression were as

```
4 + 5 + 69 * (100*3)
```

However during testing I found that the expression may also be distorted(as it is user built).
To things like

```
45+99abs - 778anv
```

So I wanted to know if there is a way of validating the user-built(expression) before sending it to be evaluated in the class ?

Comment: Side note: you don't need to do `string ExpressionToEvaluate = argExpression;` just do `Expression z = new Expression(argExpression);`

Comment: @dav_i , Yes i knw. The codes shown are not the complete ones.The string ExpressionToEvaluate Is being used in another potion of my program.Thnks.

Comment: Parsing mathematical expressions using regular expressions initially seems easy but becomes tricky very quickly. It would be easier to create a simple parser using ANTLR to validate and eventually execute your expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use CodeDom as it can perfectly do validation:

```
            CodeDomProvider provider = CSharpCodeProvider.CreateProvider("C#");
            CompilerParameters options = new CompilerParameters();
            options.GenerateExecutable = false;
            options.GenerateInMemory = true;
            // create code
            string source = "using System;namespace Expression{public static class Expression{public static void Test() {\n";
            source += expression; // your expression
            source +=";}}}";
            // compile
            var result = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, source);
            if (result.Errors.HasErrors)
                foreach (CompilerError error in result.Errors)
                    ; // use error.Column and .Row to get where error was, use .ErrorText to get actuall message, to example "Unknown variable aaa"
```

Have to leave now, hope I didn't make mistakes (if I did, someone should correct me ^^).. till Monday..

Answer (score 0):

Parsing mathematical expressions initially seems easy but becomes tricky very quickly, especially when you use regular expressions (this is a reference to your other questions).

It's easier to create a simple parser using ANTLR to validate and eventually execute your expressions. ANTLR is a very popular parser generator that is even used in ASP.NET MVC.

There are many dialects available and several great tutorials, but [the answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396080/antlr-3-3-c-sharp-tutorials) actually shows how to create a mathematical expression parser that eventually evaluates its input.

You can check the (surprisingly small) grammar file in the answer, but the actual usage is quite simple:

```
  string expression = "(12.5 + 56 / -7) * 0.5";
  ANTLRStringStream Input = new ANTLRStringStream(expression);  
  ExpressionLexer Lexer = new ExpressionLexer(Input);
  CommonTokenStream Tokens = new CommonTokenStream(Lexer);
  ExpressionParser Parser = new ExpressionParser(Tokens);
  Console.WriteLine(expression + " = " + Parser.parse());
```

The question dates to 2010 when you needed java to create your parser files from the grammar. Later versions of ANTLR removed this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

With regexes you will have a problem due to simple fact you have to validate parentheses:

```
abs(sin(log(...)))
```

You should parse the expression, not just match it against some pattern. Writing parser rules is also much cleaner and easier to understand. As a bonus you will get not only validation but also evaluation of the expression. My suite [NLT](https://sourceforge.net/projects/naivelangtools/) contains everything you need for C# (there is already simple calculator included), and say you would like to enhance it by adding `abs`.

You can omit lexer section, and go right to parser:

```
expr -> "abs" "(" e:expr ")"  // pattern
        { Math.Abs(e) };      // action
```

assuming `expr` is already defined with sum, subtraction, and so on.

*For curious soul -- not `"abs("` because in such case as `abs ( 5 )`would give error (invalid expression).*