# parsing a string to an int C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, int

I am working on math engine in C# for my teacher, and I don't know how to parse something like this `string needToBeCalculated = "1/2 + (2 + 3 /2 * (3+1))";`, To an int or long. I know that`long Calculated = long.Parse(needToBeCalculated );` this doesn't work. But is there a build in method or some kind of a design pattern that i must use ?

Comment: Simple: `double result = (double)new DataTable().Compute("1/2 + (2 + 3 /2 * (3+1))", null)` ;-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter wow, I have never seen that before. TIL.

Comment: and how do i use it if i have a math.pow ?

Comment: You can take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/392355/1677264) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4620486/1677264).

Comment: @denislavlicov: exponentiation is not supported by `Compute`, look at [the remarks section of `DataColumn.Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.90).aspx) to see what is supported.

Comment: Reminds me of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20422853/1997232) question.