# C# Regex for filtering with brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I'm sure similar questions have already been answered, but I'll give it a try anyways.

I'm trying to write some regex to parse a filter.

But my regex is weak and after playing around for awhile not working the way I want:

This is what I want:

"FirstName eq 'John' and LastName eq 'Doe'"

"FirstName eq 'John'"

"and"

"LastName eq 'Doe'"

And then after that break it down further:

"FirstName eq 'John'"

Right now I have the regex to break this down and it works the way I want

```
(\w+)\s*(eq|ne)\s*'?([^']*)'
```

"FirstName"

"eq"

"John"

But I can't figure out the regex for the first half and I also want to be able to handle and/or within the search string and brackets.

"NickName eq 'Jo or Johnny' and Name eq 'John'"

"NickName eq 'Jo or Johnny'"

"and"

"Name eq 'John'"

"FirstName eq 'John' and (LastName eq 'Doe'" or Age eq 25)"

"FirstName eq 'John'"

"and"

"LastName eq 'Doe'" or Age eq 25"

I've been staring at it for so long now I'm wondering if the approach I'm using is even worthwhile any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your post is very poorly formatted.  It's hard to understand what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Your filter looks like pretty simple expression. As Kevin states, it's a good idea to parse it with something more maintainable than regular expressions, also you will get performance boost. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396080/using-antlr-3-3) article describes how to create your own expression parser. As a result of parsing you will get syntax tree, e.g for `FirstName eq 'John' and LastName eq 'Doe'` filter there will be:

```
                 and
          /                \
        eq                  eq
      /    \             /     \
FirstName  'John'    LastName  'Doe'
```

After that you can walk and interpret AST according to your requirements.

Comment: The linked post is an **excellent** post, but keep in mind that it covers ANTLR 3.3. As of this post, the current version is 4.5.2 and may have breaking changes.

Answer (score 0):

Though not explicitly stated, it looks like you are trying to parse a grammar using Regex. While this may be possible, it is rarely the best tool for the job. Since it appears you have recursive structures in this grammar, I believe a regular expression will be impossible.

So... I would suggest you investigate some full scale grammar parsers. One such tool is ANTLR, though there are many. You can check it out at their website @ http://www.antlr.org/ and install a C# version via NuGet (https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs)

You can also roll your own in C# if ANTLR feels too heavy for the job.